# In  R  is there some function like raw_input() in python?

Tags: r

In Python, we can use `raw_input()`, what can I use in R?

```
>>> raw_input("let x=3 or 4?")
let x=3 or 4?3
'3'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `readline()`:

```
> input = readline('Enter anything: ')
Enter anything: test
> input
[1] "test"
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better solution:

```
input = readline(prompt="Enter anything: ")
```

This will will work in a interactive session

Comment: I appreciate this answer. However, I am having issues running the command in a program. R doesn't wait like Python for the input. Am I doing something wrong? I was wanting to write this in a program with some long script.

Answer (score 0):

... even more python-ish:

```
(readline(prompt = 'Enter anything: '))
```